# What symbols can I use in FAT32 volume labels?

Tags: hard-drive, fat32

Am I allowed to use spaces, dots and other symbols in volume labels?

What is the maximum length?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Maximum of 11 characters
- No `* ? . , ; : / \ | + = < > [ ] "` symbols
- Spaces allowed, no tabs

Comment: Spaces are allowed(and in NTFS too).

Comment: Don't forget the quote mark ( " ), the only character missing on your 'disallowed' list (16 disallowed chars total).

Comment: Can someone give an authoritative reference? That would help us confirm the accuracy and check for any other missing info.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions

Comment: @Aubin: That doesn't say it applies to filesystem labels (not to be confused with volume paths, which are a later WinNT invention). Filesystem labels are not part of the file path. (And it doesn't even match the limits specified in the post, e.g. the invalid character set is completely different from that of filenames.)

Comment: @user1686 volume labels were originally stored across the 11-character (normally 8 plus 3 for extension) "filename" of a special directory entry in the root directory.

Comment: @CherryDT: Yes, but they're not accessed through the "file"/"path" APIs, which is where the special character limit is from. If the OS provides a dedicated ioctl for setting the label, where none of the "wildcard" or "path separator" rules apply, then there is no reason for having character limits. (After all the actual directory entry _could_ store arbitrary bytes if the OS wanted it to.)

Comment: Linux's mkfs.vfat does not allow [this set of characters](https://github.com/dosfstools/dosfstools/blob/1da41f0e70dcbfb874e8191c639b91fa58205ea4/src/fatlabel.c#L96).